# How to get TimeWithZone within rails3 unit/test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm trying to test a rails, application, and in one particular case, I need to create a TimeWithZone object inside my testcase. So I write sth like this:

```
started_at = ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone(started_at, Time.zone)
```

only to get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `TimeWithZone' for ActiveSupport:Module
```

I tried requiring 'active_support', 'active_support/time', ''active_support/time_with_zone'. each of those statements evaluates to false when I run tests (it works fine in irb)

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `new` object:

```
started_at = ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.new(started_at, Time.zone)
```

However, you should never need to create instances of this class directly.

If you have Time.zone set up correctly already, you can simply use the `at` method on it:

```
started_at_with_zone = Time.zone.at(started_at)
```

Take a look at the [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) for details.